# GiST indexing on constantly updating PostGIS Raster table best practice

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-raster

I have a single PostGIS raster (3.x) table that holds multiple dates tiled up. I am constantly adding to this table via raster2pgsql. I want to keep the GiST index updated so I attach the -I flag but this ends up creating a new index each time and I end up with hundreds of indexes.

Is it better to drop the old index before importing more data creating a new one?

Is raster2pgsql just indexing the new data and I should just leave the old indexes there?

Generally what is the best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want to leave the indexes where they are, and worry less; **they get updated by the RDBS** - otherwise they really would be rather useless in practice.

**Do not** create more than one index for the same conditions.

---

Index maintenance is a heavy topic. Generally, no matter what you do, indexes become more or less *bloated* and/or *fragmented* in some fashion whenever their parent relations get modified; this is particularly true for (heavy) `UPDATE` & `DELETE` operations, way less so for `INSERT`s, which may affect the packing of the indexed data only.

Up to a certain degree this is unavoidable - and absolutely okay! PostgreSQL's `autovacuum` utility *usually* keeps up with data modifications, and sanitizes both index and relation pages so that formerly dead tuples (or pages even; *bloat*) can get re-used.

---

*For reference:*

With PostgreSQL 12 onward, `REINDEX` can be run `CONCURRENTLY`, meaning that it does not require an `EXCLUSIVE LOCK` on the whole table anymore - at the cost of execution time. This makes it a lot more useful when needed.

You *could* run `REINDEX TABLE <table> CONCURRENTLY;` once a month or so, in off hours. But the impact for your case would likely not be noticeable, while you should expect it to take a very long time, increasing with table sizes.